# error binding values jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to bind values to three different textboxes on corresponding testbox keydown event but it is just working for one textbox. I'm sharing my code please guide me with solution

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="BuyingPrice0" value="10" style="width:55px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="bpusd0" readonly value="1.22" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="BuyingPrice1" value="10" style="width:55px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="bpusd1" readonly value="1.22" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="BuyingPrice2" value="10" style="width:55px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="bpusd2" readonly value="1.22" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
var BindBP = function (id, BPUSD) {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $(id).val();
    var country21 = $('#CurrencyValue').val();    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: cc,
        data: { amount: amount, country: country21 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $(BPUSD).val(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 3;
    window.count = 0;
    var bp2 = $("#BuyingPrice" + window.count);
    var converted2 = $("#bpusd" + window.count);
    $(bp2).on("keydown", function () {        
        for (var i = count; i <= count - window.count; i++) {
            var bp = $("#BuyingPrice" + i);
            var converted = $("#bpusd" + i);
            BindBP(bp, converted);
        }
    });
});
```

i want to change value of bpusd checkboxes on corresponding buying price changed value but now it when i type in BuyingPrice of any id it is only getting BuyingPrice0 value. Please guide me the perfect way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Correct this line

```
var amount = $(id).val();
```

with this

```
var amount = $("'#" + id + "'").val();
```

Comment: only this line or any other line also needs modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
 var errormsg = "";
 var amount = id.val();
```

because you are already used `var bp = $("#BuyingPrice" + i);` same as for `country21`

Try as

```
var BindBP = function (id, BPUSD) {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = $(id).val();
    var country21 = $('#CurrencyValue').val();    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: cc,
        data: { amount: amount, country: country21 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            successCallBack(BPUSD,data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        }
    });
}

function successCallBack(BPUSD,data)
{
    BPUSD.val(data);
}
```

Comment: there is no error on console but it is changing all textbox values on keydown event

Comment: did u check the other point of the question? i have another function which is calling BindBp in a loop for every different id, i want to change BPUSD value on each keydown event, for example if i'm writing into BuyingPrice0 textbox then bpusd0 value should be changed respectively but now it is changing all bpusd textbox values bpusd0,bpusd1,bpusd2

Comment: do u have any other solution?